# Error in PyCharm, but not Jupyter Lab: numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I want to compare Regression models. Everything works fine with CatBoostRegressor, DecisionTreeRegressor and RandomForestRegressor.
There is a problem with LinearRegerssion: In the line with `model3.fit()` occurs an Error message:

```
raise LinAlgError("SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares")
numpy.linalg.LinAlgError: SVD did not converge in Linear Least Squares
```

This error occurs just in PyCharm, not Jupyter Lab. I am also confused because I don't use numpy in this line.
What does this mean?

This is my Code:

```
model3 = LinearRegression()

# training model3
model3.fit(
    X_train_ns_m3.drop(['PARCEL','address'], axis=1),
    y_train_ns_m3)
```

Comment: The error is likely related to your data and thus changing the data might solve the problem. You are not using NumPy yourself, but `model3.fit` is calling NumPy internally.  See [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/solve-linear-regression-using-linear-algebra/) for an explanation of linear regression, if you are curious. You will see that one way of finding the linear regression is through Singular Value Decomposition (SVD), which seems to be the one used by `model.fit`.

Comment: Please notice that any code that comes *after* the error is irrelevant to the issue (never executed) and it should not be included here as it just creates unnecessary clutter (edited out).

Comment: @darcamo : When the problem is my data (btw there are no inf or NaN values) why does it work in jupyter lab, but not in PyCharm?

Comment: I don't have a precise answer. Maybe you are using different environments in PyCharm and JupyterLab and due to precision or other reason the SVD is considered to converge in one, but not in the other. The point is that there is nothing wrong with your code neither with PyCharm (but do check that if PyCharm and JupylerLab are using different environments). From the information in the question, I can only conclude that it is due to the data, and using different data could fix the problem.

Comment: @darcamo : The environment in PyCharm and JupyterLab seems the same. It's both "Python 3.8" with the same packages. I now copied the complete model 3 in a new .py file and it works in PyCharm. I am totally confused by that. Is it possible that model 1 and 2 are the reason for this error?